# How to write query in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, oracle10g, entity

I'm new to Entity Framework. I have a database query which I need to convert to Entity Framework. how to write the query in LinQ to Enity

Can someone help me on that?

```
SELECT 
  FLD1, 
  FLD2, 
  SUM(FLD3), 
  (TO_CHAR(FLD4,'MM/DD/YYYY'))
FROM 
  TABLE1
WHERE 
  (FLD2=XXX ) AND  
  (FLD3 BETWEEN TO_DATE(VARDATE,'MMDDYYYY') AND TO_DATE(VARDATE1,'MMDDYYYY'))
GROUP BY 
  FLD1, 
  FLD2, 
  FLD4
```

Answer (score 0):

Well...info is sparse and you filled it with a lot of different cases something like this would do.

```
_context.SomeObject
     .Where(x=>x.SomeField == "SomeValue" && x.SomeField > 5 && x.SomeField < 10)
     .Select(x=>new {  x.SomeField1, x.SomeField2, x.SomeField2, SomeField4 = x.SomeChildCollection.Sum(y=>y.SomeChildvalue)
.GroupBy(x=>new {x.SomeField1, x.SomeField2, x.SomeField3})
.ToList()
```

This would result in a group where the key was an object with the values SomeField1, SomeField2, SomeField3, and the object would be the an anonymous projection with the 4 properties in the Select.

In some kinds of comparisions regarding dates you might need to use EntityFunctions.